# Prerequisites for setting up Node server with Google authentication

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, google-cloud-platform, passport-google-oauth2

I'm trying to setup a basic website with user profiles, and I thought using [passport-google](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth2) might be the simplest way. But as far as I can tell, I need some account on the [Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/) to access the API, which doesn't appear to be a free service. This isn't so much of an issue, but I don't really know which of the many products I will need, and what pricing will look like.

More succinctly, I'm trying very hard to find my

```
clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register your Client ID and Client Secret by following the steps here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project